# mocha run npm test no error details

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm

Might be a stupid issue:

I'm running a command to do unit-testing, and found that whenever there're some errors, the error message won't be printed which makes debugging really difficult. Here's the command I ran

and here's the package.json:

```
cp app/models/conversations/default_group_avatar.png built/models/conversations/default_group_avatar.png && NODE_ENV=test mocha --timeout 20000 --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-no    de/register app/**/index-test.ts --reporter nyan
```

tsconfig:

```
  1 {
  2   "compilerOptions": {
  3     "outDir": "./built",
  4     "allowJs": true,
  5     "target": "es5"
  6   },
  7   "include": [
  8     "./app/**/*.ts"
  9   ]
 10 }
```

when I run it, it shows:

```
➜  GhostFaceRestful git:(exie/robot) ✗ npm test

> ghostface@1.0.0 test /Users/exie/workspace/GhostFaceRestful
> cp app/models/conversations/default_group_avatar.png built/models/conversations/default_group_avatar.png && NODE_ENV=test mocha --timeout 20000 --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register app/**/index-test.ts --reporter nyan

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

without showing any details at all... How shall I do this correctly?

Comment: btw: If there's no error, it runs smoothly and printing the progress bar and whatnot. But when there's error it doesn't show the errors which kinda defeats the purpose of unit-testing :|

Comment: does a npm-debug.log file exist on your system?

Comment: Thanks for the response @josh . it doesn't. But sometimes there's indeed a npm-debug.log file pops up into my "git status" as an un-staged file

Comment: one thing you might try is running the command by itself (not through NPM)  and see if any errors appear in the command line

Comment: I tried to use the command directly, and it also hides errors

Comment: could you add a console log to the top of one of your test files to see if it ever makes it into the tests?

Comment: Ah! It turned out that's because tsc didn't compile correctly at the first place... follow up question, now it runs, how do I know which line of code corresponds to error like this: (node:87352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 7): [object Object]

Comment: start adding console logs in those promises :) glad you got the initial issue figured out!

Comment: @josh Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

--reporter nyan generates a cute cat cartoon in place of some of the test details.  Try running it without that option and see if you get the information you need.